# Are there existing gems or services for web hook implementations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webhooks

Most major services like github provide Webhooks functionality.

So, with github - you can set hooks to notify you on every commit.

In the same time web hooks are not that easy.

Each web hook has to be ran asynchronously to not block web server at the time of communicating with destination. And it can take a good time (10-15 seconds). There should be implemented repeating functionality (in case if destination is not responding).

So, I think that there for sure should be some service or library which will do this for you.

Do you know any of these?

I need to send data to lots of endpoints and to receive a response from them..

Comment: Use Restclient to send requests in the wild

Answer (score 2):

You need a gem providing background job functionality. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) are ones of most frequently used.

Idea is that after request (in ruby on rails you can use `after_action` hook or just do it in controller action) you create a job which will be executed asynchronously. Put logic you need in the job class

Both sidekiq and delayed job have repeating functionality, just pick gem that looks simpler to use

Comment: Yes, we're using Resque. It's not a problem to implement this, just don't want to create it from scratch if there are production - ready solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem called [ActiveHook](https://github.com/nsweeting/activehook) but it does not appear to be maintained anymore.

Benedikt Deicke wrote a good article on [sending webhooks with Rails](https://benediktdeicke.com/2017/09/sending-webhooks-with-rails/), you should check it.